# passing random numbers to a 2d array in java

Tags: java, matrix, 2d, sparse-matrix

Why am i getting erros in my code - I created two methods, randomGen to generate a random number and matrixGen to create the matrix with random numbers. I am getting incompatible types error. If someone can please point me in the right direction to what I could be doing wrong.. Im still in learning phase.. Heres my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class sparse{
    static int matrix [][] = new int[6][6];

    public static int randomGen(){
        int rA;
        Random r = new Random();
        rA = r.nextInt(100);
        return rA;
    }

    public static int[][] matrixGen(){
        for(int i=0; matrix[i].length < i; i++){
            for(int j=0; matrix[j].length <j; j++){
                matrix[i] = matrix[i].randomGen();
                matrix[j] = matrix[j].randomGen();
            }
        }
        return matrix[i][j];
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new sparse();
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Please copy and paste the *exact* error messages. Also, please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: Let there be stack traces!  And we were no longer confused.

Comment: I don't think `randomGen()` can be called on an integer or array of integer.

Comment: how do you call it to fill an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get rid of randomGen, use this:

```
public static int[][] matrixGen(){
    Random r = new Random( );
    for(int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = r.nextInt( 100 );
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

3 (update: 4) things:

1. you're using `Random` wrong. You should create it once, then get lots of numbers from it.
2. you're trying to call randomGen on an int, which makes no sense; it's a property of `sparse`, not `int`. You could have done `matrix[i][j] = randomGen()`.
3. you're doing something very odd indeed to access array elements. Hopefully this code will clear it up for you a bit.
4. your loops are odd too. I've fixed them in this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
    matrix[i] = matrix[i].randomGen();
    matrix[j] = matrix[j].randomGen();
```

needs to be this:

```
    matrix[i][j] = randomGen();
```

Comment: actually it should be `matrix[i][j] = randomGen()`: he's got his matrix indices muddled too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `matrixGen` method is confused.  Your outer `i` for loop needs to stop iterating when it reaches the length of the `matrix` array, not the length of the `i`th inner array.  Similarly, your inner `j` for loop needs to stop iterating when it reaches the length of the `matrix[i]` array.

If you want to assign a value to one particular spot in your 2D array, then you need one assignment, not two; on the left-hand side of the `=` you'll need to use *both* `i` and `j`.

You don't need to put `matrix[i]` or `matrix[j]` before your call to `randomGen`, because you defined it in the same class.

You aren't even calling the `matrixGen` method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the provided piece of code, your `main` does nothing at all, since you create an object which you don't use. I assume it is going to be continued in the future.

As to the errors you're getting, I'll also have to make assumptions, as no additional information is provided.

The errors you're encountering are probably in your `matrixGen` method, which, I assume, is supposed to populate the static matrix. It should be like this:

```
public static void matrixGen(){
    for(int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = randomGen();
        }
    }
}
```

1. `void`, as you're modifying your matrix, and not creating a new one;
2. Your loop conditions were wrong. The indexes are incremented until they reach the respective length (`i` for lines and `j` for columns);
3. Access the matrix *cell* using two indexes (line and column);
4. `randomGen` is a method from `class sparse`, and not from arrays.

**Edit:** as noted by Dave, you shouldn't also be creating a new `Random` instance every time. Either store the `Random` in a variable, as you did with the matrix, or create it before entering the loops, in this same method.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that he shouldn't create a new Random object for every random number.